# Setting Qualifiers for Bash Array

Tags: bash, array, snmp

I have a bash script that is running an SNMPGET of two values. I want to take the results and put them in an array.

Here is the code:

```
OUTPUT=`snmpget -v2c -c public -Oqv 192.168.0.33' \
' sysName'\
' SysLocation'
echo  $OUTPUT
ARRAY=($OUTPUT)
echo ${ARRAY[0]}
```

`echo  $OUTPUT` returns `"Private Network" "Server 4 "`.

When I put it in an array and do:

```
echo ${ARRAY[0]}
```

it Returns `"Private`

How do I alter my script so that the qualifier for the array, is not the space in between words so for echo `${ARRAY[0]}` it Returns `"Private Network"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ARRAY=($OUTPUT)
```

by

```
eval ARRAY=($OUTPUT)
```